# How to view PHP or Apache error log online in a browser?

Tags: php, linux, apache, logging, error-log

Is there a way to view the PHP error logs or Apache error logs in a web browser?

I find it inconvenient to ssh into multiple servers and run a "tail" command to follow the error logs. Is there some tool (preferably open source) that shows me the error logs online (streaming or non-streaming?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [What commercial and open source competitors are there to Splunk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183977/what-commercial-and-open-source-competitors-are-there-to-splunk) and I would recommend https://github.com/tobi/clarity

Simple and easy tool.

Answer (score 10):

A simple php code to read log and print:

```
<?php

  exec('tail /var/log/apache2/error.log', $error_logs);

  foreach($error_logs as $error_log) {

       echo "<br />".$error_log;
  }

 ?>
```

You can embed error_log php variable in html as per your requirement. The best part is `tail` command will load the latest errors which wont make too load on your server.

You can change `tail` to give output as you want

Ex. `tail myfile.txt -n 100` // it will give last 100 lines

Answer (score 9):

Since everyone is suggesting [clarity](https://github.com/tobi/clarity), I would also like to mention [tailon](https://github.com/gvalkov/tailon). I wrote [tailon](https://github.com/gvalkov/tailon) as a more modern and secure alternative to [clarity](https://github.com/tobi/clarity). It's still in its early stages of development, but the functionality you need is there. You may also use [wtee](http://wtee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), if you're only interested in following a single log file.

Answer (score 6):

You good make a script that reads the error logs from apache2..

```
$apache_errorlog = file_get_contents('/var/log/apache2/error.log');
```

if its not working.. trying to get it with the php functions `exec` or `shell_exec` and the command 'cat /var/log/apache2/error.log'

EDIT: If you have multi servers(i quess with webservers on it) you can create a file on the machine, when you make a request to that script(hashed connection) you get the logs from that server

Comment: Isn't this going to create a warning such as `PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/var/log/apache2/error.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied`? Of course given that a basic security system is set up.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend LogHappens: https://loghappens.com, it allows you to view the error log in web, and this is what it looks like:

[image]

LogHappens supports kinds of web server log format, it comes with parses for Apache and CakePHP, and you can write your own.

You can find it here: https://github.com/qijianjun/logHappens

It's open source and free, I forked it and do some work to make it work better in dev env or in public env. That is:

- Support token for security, one can't access the site without the token in config.php
- Support IP whitelists for security and privacy
- Sopport config the interval between ajax requests
- Support load static files from local (for local dev env)

Answer (score 1):

I've found this solution https://code.google.com/p/php-tail/

It's working perfectly. I only needed to change the filesize, because I was getting an error first.

```
56       if($maxLength > $this->maxSizeToLoad) {
57                $maxLength = $this->maxSizeToLoad;
58                // return json_encode(array("size" => $fsize, "data" =>   array("ERROR: PHPTail attempted to load more (".round(($maxLength / 1048576), 2)."MB) then the maximum size (".round(($this->maxSizeToLoad / 1048576), 2)    ."MB) of bytes into memory. You should lower the defaultUpdateTime to prevent this from happening. ")));
59       }
```

And I've added default size, but it's not needed

```
125       lastSize = <?php echo filesize($this->log) || 1000; ?>;
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a bit old, but (along with the lack of good choices) it gave me the idea to create this tiny (open source) web app. https://github.com/ToX82/logHappens. It can be used online, but I'd use an .htpasswd as a basic login system. I hope it helps.